# MYSQL fulltext search and what to use for less than 4 characters?

Tags: mysql

What's the best practice for mysql search?

Full text search for >3 characters. How to handle 3 or less characters? Use %LIKE%?
Or
Use %LIKE% or some other alternative for all search queries.

Comment: use `LENGTH()` ? It's hard to understand what you're asking without any example..

Comment: determining the length of the wuery is not the issue, just which search methods to use

Comment: Could look at [innodb_ft_min_token_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size), though dedicated non-mysql search engines perform the full text role significantly better.

Comment: Better to use LIKE for less than 4 characters